# Not getting screen resolution in custom new class

Tags: android

I am new to android development and after hours of efforts, i decided to put question here. I am trying to fetch screen resolution with the help of new class. If i implement code in MyActivity.java then it is working fine but if i try to implement code in new class then it is giving me null pointer exception.

Following is new class that i am trying to access in MyActivity class but it is not working and giving null pointer exception.

```
public class DeviceInfoClass {
    public String getScreenResolutionWidth(){           

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);        
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        return String.valueOf(screenWidth);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not able to copy in logcat

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should pass the context of the activity to the class

```
public class DeviceInfoClass {
public String getScreenResolutionWidth(Context c){           

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)c.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);        
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

    return String.valueOf(screenWidth);
}
}
```

Edit:

You can call it like that:

```
DeviceInfoClass def = new DeviceInfoClass();
String w = def.getScreenResolutionWidth(this);
Toast.makeText(this, w , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Another approach :
is to make the function static like this:

```
public class DeviceInfoClass {
public static String getScreenResolutionWidth(Context c){

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)c.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

    return String.valueOf(screenWidth);
}
}
```

and call it like that in the main activity:

```
String w = DeviceInfoClass.getScreenResolutionWidth(this);
```

Comment: and how to call it from MyActivity.java?

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Do you know something about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27165431/duplicate-value-issue-in-multiautocompletetextview

Comment: I didn't deal before with multitextviews. I'll try to figure out the problem and If I found an answer I'll post it.

Comment: This is way too complicated. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Context` instance for this. Then you are able to use the following method:

```
public static int getScreenWidth(Context context) {
  return getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
}
```

From an `Activity` you can use it like this:

```
int width = getScreenWidth(this);
```

Also do not define and use non-static classes in your `Activity`, it is a common source of memory leaks. In your case the easiest solution is to mark the `DeviceInfoClass` as `static class`.